# Angular2 HMR (hot module replacement) - remove the logs

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to ignore the logs on the HMR? It is very annoying after you make many changes because the console becomes HUGE, and it also makes it difficult to track custom logs.

This is the code in `log-apply-result.js` of the HMR module that does the logging:

```
if(!renewedModules || renewedModules.length === 0) {
    console.log("[HMR] Nothing hot updated.");
} else {
    console.log("[HMR] Updated modules:");
    renewedModules.forEach(function(moduleId) {
        console.log("[HMR]  - " + moduleId);      // <---- HERE
    });
    var numberIds = renewedModules.every(function(moduleId) {
        return typeof moduleId === "number";
    });
    if(numberIds)
        console.log("[HMR] Consider using the NamedModulesPlugin for module names.");
}
```

It doesn't look like there are any flags that can be passed in to stop this logging. For a single change, I literally get like 50 different messages in the console and that is just ridiculous. It starts to clunk up the dev tools after a while.

I could just do `console.clear()`, I feel like that is a dirty approach because it may cause problems later when I have custom logging and it also gets cleared.

Answer (score 1):

chrome devtools can filter using 
-HMR -WDS

Answer (score 0):

Another work around : You could filter the logs out. They are logged as info , chrome has info logs enabled by default. You can uncheck "info" and it should filter it out for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem radically, just comment out a line in the file
`../node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js`